# How do i get Sumifs to return a null value if the cell is null over multiple ranges

Tags: excel

I've been struggling with this for a while now, i use a Sumifs in excel to evaluate over a range of data,

My problem is that it returns the blank cells as zeros instead of blank,

is there a way to make the cell return as blank when looking at multiple ranges,

[image]

The above link is what the data looks like and the below link is what the sumifs returns, i need it to return blanks where the data is blank instead of zero,

[image]

The equation i am using is `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C;Sheet1!$A:$A;Sheet2!$A2;Sheet1!$B:$B;Sheet2!$B2)` where sheet 1 is the sheet with the data and sheet 2 is the table where the sumifs evaluates to,

Also if the value is blank in the data it must return blank, but if it is zero in the data it must return as a zero.

Please someone help me.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @MickaëlB: Consensus appears to be that [Excel formulas are on-topic here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

You can use IF condition to check if the total is zero.

> =IF(SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet2!$B2)=0,"",SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet2!$B2))

Apply cell formatting to hide zeros **0;-0;;@**

Comment: Hi Imran, thank you however i forgot to mention in that sometimes i will have a zero in the data so the sumifs will need to return that as zero, in a sense i need the sumifs to return both zeros as zeros and blanks as blanks

Comment: @RickyD You can hide zeros with cell formatting 0;-0;;@